# Call Method in Gem from Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've installed the `name_of_person` Gem into my Rails project.

This gem contains a method named `full` ([source](https://github.com/basecamp/name_of_person/blob/master/lib/name_of_person/person_name.rb#L7)).

I have a Rails model named `Film` that contains a class named `foo`.

I want to call `full` from within `foo`, like so:

```
class Film < ApplicationRecord
  def foo
    name = NameOfPerson::PersonName.full("David Heinemeier Hansson")
  end
end
```

When I try this I get this error: `uninitialized constant Film::NameOfPerson`.

I know I'm totally misunderstanding something basic about Ruby here. Please help.

Comment: Hrm. I tried changing it to: `name = ::NameOfPerson::PersonName.full("David Heinemeier Hansson")`. Now I get this error: `uninitialized constant NameOfPerson`.

Comment: What version of Rails do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @dbugger who helped me solve this one.

The problem appears to have been that the Rails gem wasn't installed correctly.

I uninstalled and re-installed the gem, and then I rebooted my Rails server. As soon as I did so both `name = NameOfPerson::PersonName.full("David Heinemeier Hansson")` and `::name = NameOfPerson::PersonName.full("David Heinemeier Hansson")` work fine.

Thanks!